# Mapping the same key for Compiling/Running code of different languages from vim

Tags: vim

I have `map <F8> : w <bar> !clang -o %< % && ./%< <CR>` inside my .vimrc, however I want to map F8 to run python codes as well. How is that possible? (obviously I don't want clang to run python, I want to have a condition or something to redirect what command F8 maps to based on the language that is already specified e.g. via :setf python etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for *filetype-specific* mappings. Put the Python variant into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`, and add the `<buffer>` keyword to the `:map` command:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F8> : w <bar> !python % <CR>
```

This requires `:filetype plugin on`, but you probably already have that. Similarly, you can move your original mapping to `ftplugin/c.vim`, or keep that as a global fallback for all filetypes.

#### Additional tips

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- Better specify the concrete modes this applies to, in this case *normal mode* via `:n[nore]map`.

Comment: I didn't know about that way of doing it. I'll be refactoring my vimrc this evening.

Comment: @chooban: Your solution works as well, but clutters all the configuration in your vimrc. Some prefer a single, centralized (huge) config, but most users fare better by using the abstractions built into Vim.

Comment: It seems like a nice level-up. Learn what you like in vim by building up a vimrc, then put it in the "correct" place when it's stable.

Answer (score 2):

Very doable. Here's an example where I have the same key mapped for tidying different types of file:

```
 autocmd FileType perl nnoremap <buffer> <F12> mz:%!perltidy<CR>`z
 autocmd FileType javascript nnoremap <buffer> <F12> :call JsBeautify()<CR>
```

It's been a while since I added this to my vimrc, but if memory and a quick google serves me well, this watched for the event of the fileype being perl or javascript, and then runs the `nnoremap` command for whichever event has occurred. I'm sure there are many other ways to accomplish it!